# C# Ignore error/warning on Substring

Tags: c#, error-handling, substring, warnings

I use Substring to decode a generated code for activating
but when a user enter wrong code like 1 or 123
c# stop and say "Index and length must refer to a location within the string." or ..
how to ignore it without check length ...

in php we can ignore warnings and error by using "@"

@myfunc(12);

but how in C# ?

Comment: No. Check the length is appropriate before attempting the `substring`

Comment: come on man , people do negative my Q because php can do and C# can Not !

Comment: ignoring an error is a bad idea and bad practice regardless of the language.

Comment: we must stop moral absolutism , we are just advance apes ...

Comment: you will want to have a `conditional` check that meets a certain criteria if it meets that Length requirement then perform the substring routine..

Comment: ...but some are more advanced than others

Comment: ...and the way we get to more advanced apes is to things properly.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't.

The correct answer is you shouldn't, and to check that the input is valid.

The horrible answer would look something like this:

```
public void SwallowExceptions(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
  }
  catch
  {
  }
}

public string DoSomething()
{
  string data = "TerribleIdea";
  string result = null;
  SwallowExceptions(() => result = data.Substring(0, 10000));
  return result;
}
```